# Not able to get response from the select query

Tags: php

I have written a code in PHP and not able to get a response from the code. Following is my code.

```
<?php

include_once("conectionFile.php");
$db = new Data();
$con = $db->Conn();

$val = $_REQUEST;

$lclQuery = "SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE st_id = ".$val."";

$lclResult = $con->query($lclQuery);

if($row = $lclResult->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                 echo $res = json_encode($row);

        }   


?>
```

Comment: try like this 
$lclQuery = "SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE st_id = '".$val."'";

Comment: st_id is an integer in the MYSQL database.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is an array, not the value that you think, so the SQL will never find a match. Although you are asking for SQL injection issues, you should be looking for the submitted reference, such as `$_REQUEST['theValue']`

Comment: Without Where condition also not getting.

Comment: $lclQuery = "SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE st_id = '".$val["theValue"]."'";

Comment: Getting Now The Problem was echo $res = json_encode($row[0]); Need to put "row[0]". Thank you for Response.

Comment: try to ver_dump your request I think because u are passing $_REQUEST so it's  array that's why you are not able to get result

Comment: Getting Now.........

Comment: Who all are downvoted please give the reason for the down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$lclQuery = "SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE st_id = ".$val."";`

You need to change your query as it is not correct also $val is array so you need to use correct key there in order to get value for example `$val = $_REQUEST['some_id']` then change query like

`$lclQuery = "SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE st_id = '".$val."'";`